# Inverse of the square matrix 3

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the matrix

$A=\left ( \begin{matrix}
 -2&-7  & -9\\ 
 2&5  & 6\\ 
 1& 3 & 4
\end{matrix} \right )$

Find the third column of $A^{-1}$ without calculating
the other columns.

The exercise refers to calculating the inverse of the matrix $A$ using elementary operations by rows (Gaussian method) or is another method ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Write the identity matrix next to A. Then using cols 1 and 2, turn col 3 of A into $(0, 0, 1)$, and do the same operations to the identity matrix column 3.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c$ be the third column of $A^{-1}$. We know that $AA^{-1}=I$.

In general, suppose we are computing $XY$, where $X$ and $Y$ are matrices of appropriate dimension. If we multiply the $i$th row of $X$ with the $j$th column of $Y$, that will yield the $(i,j)$th component of the product. For example, 
$$\begin{pmatrix}*&*&*\\x_1&x_2&x_3\\*&*&*
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} *&*&y_1\\*&*&y_2\\*&*&y_3
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}*&*&*\\*&*&x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3\\*&*&*
\end{pmatrix}$$

Armed with this knowledge, we can write $A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}*&*&c_1\\*&*&c_2\\*&*&c_3\end{pmatrix}$. 
Then, since $AA^{-1} = I$, we know that

- $A_1 \cdot c = 0$
- $A_2 \cdot c = 0$
- $A_3 \cdot c = 1$

where $A_1$ is the first row of $A$, $A_2$ is the second row of $A$, and $A_3$ is the third row of $A$. Also, $\cdot$ is the standard dot product. By doing this, you can create a system of equations which you can use to solve for the third column of $A^{-1}$.

This is just the first thought that came to my mind; there are likely quicker and better ways to do this computation.

Answer (score 0):

[BSplitter’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3172804/265466) gives you a general method that’s might be what whoever gave you this problem had in mind. Since you’re working in $\mathbb R^3$, though, you can take advantage of the existence of the cross product to simplify the calculations. As in that answer, we interpret the matrix multiplication as a set of dot products between the rows of $A$ and columns of $A^{-1}$. For the last column of $A^{-1}$, the first two of these dot products vanish, which means that it must be orthogonal to both the first and second rows of $A$. This in turn means that it must be a scalar multiple of $(-2,-7,-9)^T\times(2,5,6)^T=(3,-6,4)^T$. Now set $k(3,-6,4)^T\cdot(1,3,4)^T=1$ and solve for $k$.